# PhpStan and CakeDC/Enum, how to fix the "call to an undefined function ..:enum()"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x, phpstan

I know it's probably a silly question, but I'm struggling with it since a few hours and I can't manage to fix this error.

I am using https://github.com/CakeDC/Enum in one of my projects.

In my `src/Model/Table/CarsTable.php` I have this, in the `initialize()` method:

```
    $this->addBehavior('CakeDC/Enum.Enum', ['lists' => [
        'stato' => [
            'strategy' => 'const',
            'prefix' => 'STATO'
        ]
    ]]);
```

While in my `CarsController` I have this

```
/**
* Cars Controller
*
* @property \App\Model\Table\CarsTable $Cars
* @property \App\Controller\Component\PermissionComponent $Permission
* @property \App\Controller\Component\LoggerComponent $Logger
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Car[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
*/
class CarsController extends AppController
{
    ...

    public function add()
    {
        ...
        $this->set('stato', $this->Cars->enum('stato'));
        ...
    }
```

The `enum` method is inherited from its plugin, it's not a method in my `CarsTable`. This means that when I run `phpstan analyze src` I get this error:

```
Line   Controller/CarsController.php                                   
69     Call to an undefined method App\Model\Table\CarsTable::enum().
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If its just phpstan complaining than suppress the phpstan warning or is there any actual problem with the library? https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors

Comment: I think the issue is with the controller's methods declaration. There is probably an easy way to fix this without just ignoring the error, but yeah I suppose that suppressing the warning would work as a plan B...

Comment: It's not the most elegant solution for sure. But phpstan is correct. Technically the method does not exist. You might want to raise it as an issue on github and see what the author recommends. That enum method is getting applied to the class "magically".